# How to apply JSON data to an EmberJS Model Attribute

Tags: json, ember.js

I'm very new to JS and I'm retrying EmberJS due to the impending 2.0 but especially because of EMBER CLI which I really like the structure.

Anyways, I'm building a basic app and what I'm currently looking to do is make a JSON call to reddit to grab the subscriber number and apply that number to a models subscriber number attribute. I'll also be cycling through an array of models too.

So for my instance, I've got models of lets say sports teams. Each team as a subreddit and when someone clicks the league they want, I'll be displaying all of the teams in that league.

I've got the the JSON working from a pure JS aspect, and I've got the Ember app working w/o any JSON. So I'm just trying to figure out how to connect the two while also realizing I will probably need to do some tear down to properly connect the two.

So my question is, how do I go about selecting a single piece of data from Reddit API to a single model attribute?

Here is the JS I'm using currently to pull the subscriber number.

```
$.each( teamList, function( key, val ) {
  $.getJSON(
    "http://api.reddit.com/r/"+val+"/about",
    function foo(data)
    {
      $("#team").append(val + " : ");
      $("#team").append(data.data.subscribers + '<br>');
    }
  );
});
```

My current ember model setup is normal, but I am using fixtures since all data is static other than this model attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to [customise an adapter](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/customizing-adapters/) that pulls data from the API and possibly implement a custom serializer..

The guides would be a good place to start